# What does the `at` method of a Mojo::Dom object do?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

Just came across in the following code:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use lib './lib/lib/perl5';

use Mojo::DOM;

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new($html);
my $table = $dom->at('table');
for my $record ($table->children('tr')->each) 
my %record = map { $_->text } $record->children('td')->each;
```

What exactly does the `at` method do here?

Answer (score 7):

[`at`](http://p3rl.org/Mojo%3a%3aDOM#at), in this case, is a method called on the `$dom` variable, which is an instance of [`Mojo::DOM`](http://p3rl.org/Mojo%3a%3aDOM). The documentation tells us that the `at` method is used to

> Find a single element with CSS selectors. All selectors from Mojo::DOM::CSS are supported.

Answer (score 7):

Its a special case of [`find`](https://metacpan.org/module/Mojo%3a%3aDOM#find) that returns the first match. `find` returns a `Mojo::Collection` object (blessed arrayref) filled with `Mojo::DOM` objects representing matches. When you use `at` you get the first match directly as a `Mojo::DOM` object. This is just convenience. In fact the method is exactly

```
sub at { shift->find(@_)->[0] }
```

The code presented skips some of the power of Mojo::Collection. I might write the above as:

```
my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new($html);
my @records = $dom->at('table')->find('tr td')->pluck('text')->each;
```

of course depending on the specifics.